# Joomla add component to database

Tags: joomla

I'm just starting out on a component for Joomla. I can't figure out how to add an entry in the dB so I can access the component.

I looked at the dB table for components, but some of the columns seem to require some specific info.

This is NOT a finished component, but a new one I want to build.

I am using Joomla 1.7.

take care,
lee

Comment: if you want to develop your own component then you have two option one is to enter the requirement direct into the database in `component` table second is through xml file, make sure that direct enter values in database is not the right way then follow the slandered with xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jogesh_p suggested, the easy way is to create an xml file like this 
http://docs.joomla.org/Components:xml_installfile

If you are just starting out with Joomla development then take a look at the Hello World tutorial.
http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_01

Another option to create a Joomla component quickly is to use EasyCreator, which will create the basic parts of the extension that you can then build on.

Comment: Thanks, I found something like EasyCreator that created all the basic file structures and XML to import into Joomla. Thanks.